# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type error

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to convert a pointer to a struct to a integer however I get the following error in the 2 pointers in question.

```
int value = 0;
int trig = 0;
int Echo =0;
void* threadFunc(void *args) {
   if(args!= NULL){
   struct args *pins = malloc(sizeof(args));
   trig = pins->trig1;//edited
   echo = pins->echo1;//edited
    value = setup();
   }
}
```

The snippet of code above is called from another file, which creates the thread passing the struct

```
struct sonicPins{
//front left.
int trig1;
int echo1;
//front right.
int trig2;
int echo2;
//rear left;
int trig3;
int echo3;
//rear right.
int trig4;
int echo4;
};

struct sonicPins *args1;
args1-> trig1 = 21;
args1->echo1 = 20;
//front right.
args1->trig2 = 16;
args1->echo2 = 12;
//rear left;
args1-> trig3 = 26;
args1->echo3 = 19;
//rear right.
args1->trig4 = 13;
args1->echo4 = 6;

if(args1!=NULL){
 pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, &threadFunc,(void*) &args1);
}
```

The following error I get during compilation: sonicThread.c: In function ‘threadFunc’:
sonicThread.c:9:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
sonicThread.c:10:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

I have tried for ages trying to resolve the issue but to no avail.

Comment: The definition of the struct seems to be invisible for the first snippet. Probably it is defined after the function definition.

Comment: The definition is in the first snippets header file and is exported using extern I am not sure why the struct would be invisible when its passed as an argument. But if this is the case am not sure how to fix the issue.

Comment: You might want to show *all* of the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: This is all the reverent parts of the code but happy to add the headers relating to this but you'll only see definitions of functions and includes of libraries. main files header contains the following:  #include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sonicNav.h"
#include "sonicThread.h" sonicThread.h contains the following: #include<pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<wiringPi.h>
extern void* threadFunc(void *args);

Comment: The second snippet uses `struct sonicPins` whereas the first snippet uses `struct args`. Me thinks there is no such thing as `struct args`.

Comment: tried that but that doesn't change anything. If I don't have the 2 pointers in the threadFunc the code will compile. So it seems to be down to the 2 pointers

Answer (score 0):

The line `struct args *pins = malloc(sizeof(args));` uses a `struct args` and next asks for the `sizeof(args)`. `struct args *` is a forward declaration; it means "*I am referencing  something (by pointer) that you will learn about later, but that's not important now, just reserve space for a pointer.*"

At some point in your code there must now be a

```
typedef struct args {
    ....
} args;
```

which declares a `struct args`, its definition and an alternative name for it, `args`. However, when the compiler parses `struct args *pins = malloc(sizeof(args));` it hasn't seen the definition of `args`, so it doesn't know its size, and complains about it.

EDIT: In addition, in the function which creates the thread passing the struct, you declare a `struct sonicPins *args1;` but do not allocate memory for it, however, you do as if when you start assigning values to it. Amazing that you don't get a seg fault. But anyway, you should do:

```
struct sonicPins *args1= malloc(sizeof(struct sonicPins));
args1->trig1 = 21;
args1->echo1 = 20;
....
```

Now that you have safely alocated memory for it, you can pass it to the thread function.

```
pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, &threadFunc,(void*) &args1);
```

Now that the thread function gets already allocated memory, it doesn't need to do that (but that was the compiler error that we discussed first), the function becomes:

```
int value = 0;
int trig = 0;
int Echo =0;
void* threadFunc(struct sonicPins *args) {
   if(args!= NULL){
       trig = args->trig1;
       echo = args->echo1;
       value = setup();
   }
   /* and what does it return?? */
}
```

**EDIT:** so the structure of your files must be:

File sonic.h contains the defintion:

```
/* file sonic.h */
typedef struct sonicPins{
    //front left.
    int trig1;
    int echo1;
    ...
} args;
```

File main.c includes this and allocates the storage to pass to the thread function:

```
/* main.c */
#include "sonic.h"

struct sonicPins *args1;

int main() {
    ...
    args1= malloc(sizeof(struct sonicPins));
    args1->trig1= 21;
    ...
    pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, threadFunc, args1);
    ...
}
```

And the file with threadFunc looks like:

```
/* threadFunc.c*/
#include "sonic.h"

int value = 0;
int trig = 0;
int Echo =0;
void* threadFunc(struct sonicPins *args) {
    if(args!= NULL){
        trig = args->trig1;
        echo = args->echo1;
        value = setup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to C I did alter my struct as you suggested and your totally right, the structFunc &args has a totally different memory address compared to printing the pointer which is passed into the create thread. I am really not sure how to correct the problem.

Comment: Make sure the compiler has SEEN the definition. Place the definition of the `typedef` in a .h file and include it in the relevant source files. You are having trouble with some very basic aspects of C. I suggest you find someone near you to help you as it will go beyond what we can discuss here.

Comment: Does the last edit solve your problem? I donlt think I can get into more detail.

Comment: Yes fixed most of the issues however the compiler is not happy about passing the pointer to the function: mainRobo.c:27:2: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(struct sonicPins *)’

Comment: PS you cannot call a function which contains anything other than void as an argument from pthread_create as it only expects a void *

Comment: RE: `void *` is a pointer to anything. The "anything" in your case will be a `struct sonicPins` (or a pointer to it). That `pthread` wants a `void *` is because it doesn't want to know, nor wants to dictate, what you want to pass. You can safely ignore this warning, or you can cast it like (`void * ()(void *))threadfunc` (and don't use the `&` operator on the function name; the compiler will do that).

Comment: Thank you but I have got the issue resolved and the file is working. Thank you community for your input

Comment: I am happy to hear it all works now. Please click on the vote at the top of my answer to accept it - that's how this community works.

Comment: In `malloc(sizeof(args));`, `args` is a parameter to the function. There's no reason to belive there is a `typedef struct args{....}args;` anywhere.  `struct args *` is not a forward declaration; that line is declaring and initializing a variable. Your advice to add a typedef `args` is pointless and IMHO confusing.

Comment: `pthread_create(&thr1, NULL, &threadFunc,(void*) &args1);` passes a `struct sonicPins **` to the function, and includes a superfluous cast. But the function treats it as if you passed a `struct sonicPins *`, causing UB.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, you are right about the call to `pthread_crfeate`; I updated my answer. There was quite some things wrong with this post. I also could have explained the original problem/question better. Question for me was whether the `sizeof` operates here on a variable or on a type. I assumed a type. If it was on a variable, then only space fo a pointer would be allocated, but that is not what his compiler complained about; it complained about `error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type`. Maybe that was the next line

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes I'd say that error came from the next line where `->` is used on pointer to incomplete type